# How to Save Password in rasdial?

Tags: windows, vpn

guys.

I want to use the windows RASDIAL in my app to connect to a VPN.

I'm using this cmd command:

```
rasdial a-1 username pass
```

I just want to know, how to save password in this command for the next connects?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Probably the OP already solve the problem (asked 4 years ago), but `rasdial` can't save the password. But you can use your stored credentials in Windows with `rasphone`. Remember to uncheck "Prompt for name and password, certificate, etc." in the connection properties to skip the dialog.

> You can use rasphone.exe to dial a connection using stored credentials:
>
> `rasphone -d "VPN NAME"`
>
> Hangup with:
>
> `rasphone -h "VPN NAME"`
>
> You'll also need to go into the option tab of the properties for your VPN connection and uncheck "Prompt for name and password, certificate, etc."

https://superuser.com/a/894969/27235

Answer (score 5):

In Windows 10, `rasphone` will always prompt for credentials (Option to skip this step is gone. Thanks, Microsoft!). But I was able to use my saved password with `rasdial` by using EAP authentication:

[image]

Without EAP, MS-CHAP v2 does not work.

Now I can just execute `rasdial VpnName`, and it uses my saved password.

Comment: How to add user and pass into the rasphone.pbk?

Comment: I hit the same issue with Windows 10, but it seems you can edit a file to prevent the password dialog from popping up: Change `PreviewUserPw=1` to `PreviewUserPw=0` for your VPN connection in the %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk file
Read more here: https://superuser.com/a/1027290/282850

Answer (score 3):

To connect to VPN without user interaction and to avoid write down the password in the batch file you can use ...

`rasphone -d VPNname`

... and remove "Prompt for Username and password" dialog with this answer ... https://superuser.com/a/1027290/418793